# How do I change elements position inside td tag

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a page which has other sub-tables inside one big table that divides the whole page into 2 parts. My question is how can I change position of all elements inside `td` tags in order to look it nice? The result I have now is here:

[Current result with no position formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4TSL.png)

I want it to look like like this:

[The way it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Bx5.png)

I've tried to do it with CSS formatting using relative position feature like this

```
.leftSide
{
    position: relative;
    bottom:250px;
}
```

And it works so well, but when I zoom in- zoom out this page in the browser it becomes a one big mess(elements by default in the middle of `td` tag, but then I do it, elements are out of the table). How can I avoid it?
My whole code below:

```css
.splitTable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #05788D;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sides {
  border: 6px solid #05788D;
}

.SSRSSObjectCostTableTest {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 30%;
}

.sideForSSRSSTables {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
}

.partsTable {
  height: 7%;
  width: 95%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sideForPartsTable {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
}

.leftSide {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 250px;
}

.rightSide {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 250px;
}
```

```html
<table class="splitTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="sides">
      <div class="leftSide">
        <span class="chooseText">Choose</span>
        <table class="SSRSSObjectCostTableTest" width="25%">
          <tr>
            <td class="sideForSSRSSTables">Say this is 1st element</td>
            <td class="sideForSSRSSTables">Say this is 2nd element</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td class="sides">
      <div class="rightSide">
        <span class="partsText">Parts</span>
        <button type="button" class="addButton">+Add Part</button>

        <!--<table class="outerPartTable">-->

        <table class="partsTable">
          <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">Expand button</td>
          <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title + sum1 + sum2</td>
          <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">edit</td>
          <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">remove</td>

        </table>
        <!--</table>-->
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try em or % instead of px ex. `.leftSide
{
    position: relative;
    bottom:50% ;  // or 15.625em
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, this helps :)

```css
.splitTable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 6px solid #05788D;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sides {
  border: 6px solid #05788D;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}


.sideForSSRSSTables {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
}

.partsTable {
  height: 7%;
  width: 95%;
  margin-top:30px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sideForPartsTable {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
}

.leftSide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:flex-end;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width:90%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}

.leftSide>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.SSRSSObjectCostTableTest {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
  margin: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


.rightSide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  width:90%;
}

.addButton {
  float:right;
  margin-right:5%;
}
```

```html
<table class="splitTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="sides">
      <div class="leftSide">
        <span class="chooseText">Choose</span>
        <table class="SSRSSObjectCostTableTest">
          <tr>
            <td class="sideForSSRSSTables">Say this is 1st element</td>
            <td class="sideForSSRSSTables">Say this is 2nd element</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td class="sides">
      <div class="rightSide">
        <span class="partsText">Parts</span>
        <button type="button" class="addButton">+Add Part</button>

        <!--<table class="outerPartTable">-->

        <table class="partsTable">
          <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">Expand button</td>
          <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title + sum1 + sum2</td>
          <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">edit</td>
          <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">remove</td>

        </table>
        <!--</table>-->
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @RobertBaratheon No problem :) Make sure to accept the answer. Cheers King of the Seven Kingdoms

Comment: Here's another dumb question.. subTable on the left side is a little bit wrong(crosses the midline). It cannot be avoided, can it? But anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @RobertBaratheon You'll have to change the entire layout and make use of flexbox instead of table to make it flexible to avoid that.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much for help! :)